# How to represent a ranked number as a percentage?

Tags: percentages

I couldn't do better with the title so let me try and explain:

Say I have two numbers: `items` and `rank`.

`items` is the number of items in a sorted list.

`rank` is the rank of the item I'm concerned with.

If `items=8` and `rank=1`, I would like the percentage to be 100%.

If `items=8` and `rank=8`, I would like the percentage to be 0%.

What should the percentage be if `items=8` and `rank=3`? I want to be able to figure this out for any `rank`.

I would greatly appreciate a solution with an explanation, and a name for what this concept is called.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like percentile to me. Use linear equation. Let x=rank, y= percentage. We have two points: $(1,100)$ and $(8,0)$. Slope is then $\frac{0-100}{8-1}=\frac{-100}{7}$. Then use point slope form $y-0=\frac{-100}{7} (x-8)$. This gives the linear equation. Now plug $x=3$ into it, you will get the percentage when rank=3, which is 71.57.

Comment: Let me add that for $A$ items and rank $r$, the general form of this answer is $$ p = \frac{100}{A - 1} (A - r),$$ where $p$ is the percentage you're looking for.

Comment: @John Is there a name for this equation?

Comment: @KittyL Thank you. Exactly what I need.